# Overlying bar graph in R using total values & subset values?

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have a dataset of new customers & active customers (new and existing) per year, over 50 years, and I would like to create a bar graph where the bar with new customers sits in the bar (that is, both starts from the X-axis) with active customers, but so far I could only find ggplot codes to do stacked bar graph, or grouped bar graph, which is not what I want.

Example data:

```
   Year           Active         New
1 1970               1            1
2 1971               1            0
3 1972               1            0
4 1973               2            1
5 1974               3            1
6 1975               8            5
...
51 2020             268          65
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Using tidyverse syntax, try reshaping the data to include "new" customer and "old" customer accounts. Then, you can fill (or shade, etc.) based on account type. See:

```
data1 <- data.frame(Year = 1970:1975,
                    Active = c(1,1,1,2,3,8),
                    New = c(1,0,0,1,1,5))

data1 %>%
  mutate(Old = Active - New) %>%
  select(-Active) %>%
  pivot_longer(-Year, names_to = "Type", values_to = "Count") %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_col(aes(x = Year, y = Count, fill = Type))
```